# Getting output from Google script to a html page

Tags: jquery, html, api, google-apps-script

Currently I am inserting data into my Google Script like a database and I want to now pull that information from the sheet to my HTML page.

For that I have tried to create a google sheet script, that gives out a result of a cell, that i want to get passed to my website.

[this script](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5RzvUWSEOjerJpouxN72wpsgpsF8IWQo2AvjZUdRPcqskz28/exec) returns the value 1

But how can i get that result from the script, to my website?

I've tried using JQuery with no success [below]

```js
var urlToGoogleSheetCells = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5RzvUWSEOjerJpouxN72wpsgpsF8IWQo2AvjZUdRPcqskz28/exec";

    $http.get(urlToGoogleSheetCells)

  ....
```

- Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Isn't this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/).

> The Apps Script Execution API is a REST interface that lets a third-party application call a function defined in an Apps Script project and receive a response. This API lets you expose the full utility of Apps Script to any application, including Android and iOS apps.